# Create dynamic marker icons on angular google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) to show some markers on the map. In my web app I would like to show around 200 markers numbered from 1-200. They should look something like this:

[image: pic 15]

Now it seems to me the wrong way to create 200 pictures with different numbers in them, so I was thinking about having one picture with white space and then have a `<div/>` that gets me the number in there. However, I am utterly stuck and cannot find a solution on the web.

My HTML code to display the markers looks like this:

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="selectedCar.checkpoints"
                 coords="'Location'"
                 idkey="'Id'"
                 icon="'Icon'">
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

Comment: Checkout this post, http://humaan.com/custom-html-markers-google-maps/

Comment: interesting idea, but unfortunately only available for google maps straight, not in combination with angular-google-maps

Comment: I think rather using this Angular Google Map, you can create your directory for google map, since its quite easy and it will open many ways to customize your map. Integrating Google Map in angular is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a label in the marker options:

```
options: {
  icon:'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png',
  labelContent: "NUMBER HERE",
  labelClass: "ClusterLabel",
  labelAnchor: "30 34"
}
```

Then you'll get something like this

[image: l]

http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/marker See api->marker->options